# bybit rest api set take profit order

Tags: python, bybit

i am trying to set take profit order with bybit rest api (testnet) 
i followd the docs https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/position/trading-stop
but i just cant get it to work
i try to changing :
position_idx to 0 1 2 
all so change tpsl_mode to full ,removing stop_loss changing and removing all non required fields
nothing workt
in this last one i get error:
`'{"retCode":10001,"retMsg":"empty value: apiTimestamp[] apiKey[] apiSignature[]","result":{},"retExtInfo":{},"time":1690745497593}'`

```
def set_take_profit_bybit(symbol,profit_price,quantity):
BASE_URL = 'https://api-testnet.bybit.com'
SET_ISO_ENDPOINT='/v5/position/trading-stop'
endpoint = BASE_URL + SET_ISO_ENDPOINT

timestamp = int(time.time() * 1000)
stop_loss=0
tp_trigger_by='MarkPrice'
sl_trigger_by='IndexPrice'
category='linear'
tpsl_mode='Partial'
tp_order_type='Limit'
sl_order_type='Limit'
tp_size=quantity
sl_size=quantity
tp_limit_price='0.49'
sl_limit_price='0.21'
position_idx=2



payload = {
    "api_key": API_KEY,
    "category": category,
    "symbol": symbol,
    "takeProfit": profit_price,
    "stopLoss": stop_loss,
    "tpTriggerBy": tp_trigger_by,
    "slTriggerBy": sl_trigger_by,
    "tpslMode": tpsl_mode,
    "tpOrderType": tp_order_type,
    "slOrderType": sl_order_type,
    "tpSize": tp_size,
    "slSize": sl_size,
    "tpLimitPrice": tp_limit_price,
    "slLimitPrice": sl_limit_price,
    "positionIdx": position_idx,
    "timestamp": timestamp,
}

signature = create_signature(API_SECRET, payload)
payload["sign"] = signature

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to bybit official Telegram bybit api channel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).